# How can I separate values from the below dataframe to widen it based on a certain word - using Pandas or Excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, text

I have the below dataframe with data that looks like this:(Made up data for clarification)

| Info | Values |
| --- | --- |
| ID | 53312 |
| State | Mass |
| Address | Stackoverflowtown |
| ID | 56120 |
| State: | Bos |
| Address | Georgetown |
| Name: | James |

There are a lot of lines but the issue I am having is that I want the data that is under a certain ID to be in width form because ID, State, Address belong to the same ID- then for the next line where we also have a Name (ID, State, Address, Name) all belong to the same ID.

**Question:**
Is there a way using Python Pandas or Excel to make it so that table would look something more like this:(Where we use ID as the index)

| ID | State | Address | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 53312 | Mass | Stackoverflowtown |  |
| 56120 | Bos | Georgetown | James |

I tried to do a pivot in Python but the issue is that since the values are all originally under the same column , when pivoted for me they end up showing each Value (ID, sTATE, Address..etc) on a different line and values in the same line would be blank- it looks something like this which is not right:

Example for ID 53312:

| ID | State | Address | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 53312 | Null | Null | Null |
| Null | Mass | NULL | NULL |
| Null | NULL | Stackoverflowtown | NULL |
| Null | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Below Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Info':['ID','State','Address','ID','State','Address','Name'],
              'Values':[53312,'Mass','Stackoverflowtown',56120,'Bos','Georgetown','James']})


df['cumcount'] = df.groupby('Info')['Info'].transform('cumcount')

df['cumcount'] = np.where(df['cumcount'] < df['cumcount'].shift(), df['cumcount'].shift(), df['cumcount'])

pd.pivot_table(df,index='cumcount',
                      columns='Info',
                      values='Values',
                      aggfunc='first' ).reset_index()[['ID','State','Address','Name']].\
                      fillna('').\
                      rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, could you kindly clarify what your thinking was on this and the np.where statement?

Comment: The code is trying to create a window on values in Column ID. For the sake of clarity, all the intermediate columns are kept separately in code. You should try to run each parts separately, for e.g you can add extra columns for df['cumcount'] < df['cumcount'].shift() in dataframe & check their output.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve this is if you are *certain* that the `ID` row comes *before* all of the other info for that ID.

If you do have this assurance, the following will work, where `df` is the original DataFrame in your post:

```py
ids = df.query("Info == 'ID'")['Values']
ids.name = 'ID'

df = df.join(ids)
df['ID'] = df['ID'].ffill()
df.query("Info != 'ID'", inplace=True)

res = df.pivot('ID', 'Info', 'Values')
```

Output of `res`:

[image]

Comment: really interesting way as well, I did try the first answer and it worked-ish so I am all good. thank you for your time though!

Comment: quick question, I am trying your method to see if it works better but I am confused a bit. you named the series ID and the columns had a value of ID so in the line after join, do you use the column value ID or the new series ID?

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out. thank you!!